# Unit test data success/failure/count not being passed to SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I use sonarqube for analyzing a project with mixed Java / Groovy tests. The Java tests are run via TestNG, whereas the Groovy tests are run via JUnit. When running the Gradle "sonarqube" task, I get the following in build log (with --debug option):

```
14:38:53.842 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Class not found in resource cache : a.b.c.SomeSpec
14:38:53.842 [WARN] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Resource not found: a.b.c.SomeSpec
```

This is only logged for Groovy tests.

I use two separate tasks to run JUnit / TestNG tests, and a JacocoMerge task from the Gradle Jacoco plugin to merge the binary reports from those tests. As a result, Sonarqube displays the coverage percentage correctly, however, when displaying the list of unit tests, all JUnit (hence, Groovy in my case) tests are missing.

I read [No Unit Test Success data for tests written in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005808/no-unit-test-success-data-for-tests-written-in-groovy/31021094#31021094?newreg=3c0ce50f157c43d795308b7e251241ae) and tried using the latest version of the plugin, however, the issue still persists. Is there any way to get both coverage AND unit test information to be displayed properly in Sonarqube using the SonarQube Gradle plugin?

I used SonarQube version 5.6.3., sonarQube Groovy plugin version 1.4 and sonarqube-gradle-plugin version 2.2

Comment: Update: on a hunch, I made a small project consisting of one Java and one groovy test. Turns out that for my big project the GroovySensor doesn't get activated. That is because during language analysis (with log output such as `18:45:32.977 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Language of file 'a/b/c/SomeClass.java' is detected to be 'java'`) groovy files in _src/test/groovy_ are not considered, even though the logs say `18:45:32.903 [INFO] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Test paths: src/test/resources, src/test/java, src/test/groovy`. What option could I be missing?